# Valuation of $\zeta_p-1$ coincides with valuation of $\zeta_p^i-1$ for $i$ not a multiple of $p$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider a number field $K$, and a finite place $v$ of $K$. Extend $v$ to $w$ on $\overline{K}$. Let $\zeta_p$ be a $p$-th root of unity in $\overline{K}$. I've been wondering whether the following holds. Is it true that $w(\zeta_p-1)=w(\zeta_p^i-1)$ for all $p\nmid i$?. i.e do we have $$w(\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\zeta_p^j)=0$$ for all $p\nmid i$ ? I think it's true if $v\nmid p$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L=K(\zeta_p),O=\{ a\in L,w(a) \ge 0\}, m=\{a\in L,w(a)>0\}$

- If $char(O/m)=p$

  In the finite field $O/m$ we have $b=c$ iff $b^p=c^p$,
  so $\zeta_p=1$ and $\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \zeta_p^j=i$ in $O/m$.
  For $p\nmid i$ it means that $$w(\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \zeta_p^j)=w(i)=0$$
  $$w(\zeta_p^i-1)=w(\zeta_p-1)=\frac{w(\prod_{i=1}^{p-1} (1-\zeta_p^i))}{p-1}=\frac{w(p)}{p-1}=\frac{1}{p-1}$$
- If $char(O/m)\ne p$ then (again in $O/m$) $\zeta_p^i$ is a $p$-th root of unity so $\zeta_p^i\ne 1$ and $w(\zeta_p^i-1)=0$.

Comment: Thank you! The first bullet point makes sense to me, in the second could you please explain how you got that $w(\zeta_p^i-1)=0$?

Comment: $\zeta_p^i-1$ is non-zero in the residue field $O/m$

Comment: Oh right so it's a unit in $O$. Got it thanks

Answer (score 1):

The point is that $x = \frac{1-\zeta_p}{1-\zeta_p^i}$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z[\zeta_p]$ (i.e. an element of $\mathbb Z[\zeta_p]^\times$). Hence, for any valuation $v$, we have $v(x) = 0$, so $v(\zeta_p - 1) = v(\zeta_p^i - 1)$.

Indeed, it is enough to show that both $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are elements of $\mathbb Z[\zeta_p]$. Clearly $x^{-1}$ is: we have $x^{-1} = 1+ \zeta_p+\cdots + \zeta_p^{i-1}$.

Conversely, since $i$ is prime to $p$, $\zeta_p^i$ is also a primitive root of unity, so we can write $\zeta_p = (\zeta_p^i)^j$ for some $j$, with $p\nmid j$. Hence
$$x = \frac{1-\zeta_p^{ij}}{1-\zeta_p^i} = 1 + \zeta_p^i+ \zeta_p^{2i} + \cdots + \zeta_p^{(j-1)i}\in \mathbb Z[\zeta_p].$$

Note that, if $p\mid i$, then this argument breaks down: in that case $1-\zeta_p^i = 0$, so $x$ cannot be defined.